# Using a value from a other table in a trigger

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I am new to triggers so i don't really understand that much. But what i'm trying to do is writing a trigger that checks if an employee salary is equal to or higher than the salary of that specific function.

My trigger for now looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Salary_check
ON Employee
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS

    DECLARE @function_id INT 
    DECLARE @salaris MONEY
    DECLARE @function_salary MONEY

    @function_id = SELECT function_id from INSERTED

    @salaris =  SELECT salary
    FROM Employee
    WHERE emp_id = (SELECT emp_id from INSERTED)

    @function_salary = SELECT salary
    FROM Function
    WHERE id = @function_id

    IF @salaris < @function_salary
    BEGIN 
        RAISERROR(‘Salary of an employee should be equal or higher to the required salary of the specific function. ’);
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END; 
GO
```

I wanted know if my @function_salary is a valid value. Because i retrieve it from the function table and not employee table? (function_id is a foreign key that references the table function (id) )

Comment: Side note: Your trigger has a **Major flaw** in it as it assumes only one record will be inserted or updated each time. **This is wrong** since DML triggers in TSQL are **fired per statement, not per row.** This means that if your insert or update statement will effect multiple rows, you will have multiple rows in the inserted and deleted pseudo tables and your trigger will fail.

Comment: @zoharPeled Thanks man!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple syntax and logical problems in the trigger.  I would suggest that you review the trigger examples in the documentation.

The trigger should look more like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Salary_check ON Employee AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS BEGIN    
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM inserted i JOIN
                     function f
                     ON f.function_id = i.function_id
                WHERE i.salary < f.salary OR i.salary IS NULL
               )
       )
    BEGIN 
        RAISERROR('Salary of an employee should be equal or higher to the required salary of the specific function.');
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END; 
END;  -- trigger
GO
```

Comment: Methinks the comparison got a bit confused in the shuffle. It should be `i.salary < f.salary` when checking for an individual salary _violating_ the "equal or higher" rule for a job function.

Comment: @Habo . . . Yes.  Thank you.